# How to keep the whitespaces when reading an attribute value with libxml2

Tags: xml, schema, whitespace, dtd, libxml2

I use **libxml2** for parsing my XML configuration file. The newest feature request involves the "correct handling of **meaningful whitespaces**", e.g. newlines should be kept.

Currently I get the attribute values with [xmlGetProp](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlGetProp).

I know that usually the whitespaces are *normalized* by the XML parser -- as the standard requests it (replacing all whitespaces with space char, fusing multiple space chars, stripping leading and trailing space chars).

I wonder if there is a way how I can make sure the embedded newlines in the attributes are kept.

- Can I use a different *libxml2* feature to parse XML-attributes keeping the spaces?
- Is there any *DTD* or *schema* way to make *libxml2* to do that? Currently I do not use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the `xml:space` attribute or the [xmlNodeGetSpacePreserve()](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeGetSpacePreserve) :

> `<para xml:space="preserve">`

See :

1. [xmlNodeGetSpacePreserve() @ LibXML documentation](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeGetSpacePreserve) ;
2. [XML to preserve the whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6250790/802365) ;
3. [White Space @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx).

Comment: Uh, interesting. No, I did not try it, but interesting  nonetheless. Alas, I do have an *attribute* and not an *element* with text content (or PCDATA or CDATA) in it. Before I can promote these horrible attributes to elements with content I will probably put an URI in the attribute and load the space-containing stuff afterwards, externally so to speak. But if there is an "attribute-way" I may be saved from doing that.

Comment: `xml:space` doesn't preserve newlines in an attribute value. It is necessary to encode newlines as `#xA;` to survive the xml parsing process unscathed according to the [rules for Attribute-Value Normalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#AVNormalize). A raw newline will become a space. Further normalization (trimming and collapse of consecutive spaces) occurs for attributes whose type is other than CDATA. (CDATA is the default type of attributes.)

Answer (score 1):

As you note this is required by the XML spec, so there is no way in DTD or Schema to stop the normalisation.

You can probably use libxml's html parser though, using its command-line xmllint utility with an input file of

```
<a>
<b x="1
2
3"/>
</a>
```

I get

```
$ xmllint abc.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
<b x="1 2 3"/>
</a>
```

so the newlines have gone, but:

```
$ xmllint --html abc.xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><a>
<b x="1
2
3"></b>
</a></body></html>
```

Newlines kept (spurious inferred html and body added but you could lose them post parsing in your application).